# What languange does Kops API require?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, containers, kops

I have a question regarding to kops developed by kubernetes.
Does it provide an API and if so what programing languange?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Kops uses Kubernetes API resources, take a look [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/development/api_updates.md).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the cluster spec, it references Kops API ( written in go ):
https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kops/pkg/apis/kops

so with a small wrapper script or some midelware you can achieve a full api.

another interesting option is to use Kops toolbox and the templating ( go based ):
https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cluster_template.md